# Show that the only extreme point of $\text{Ray}(\bar x,\text{d})$ is $\bar x$. where $\text{Ray}(\bar x,\text{d}):=\{\bar x+t\text{d}:t \ge 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Show that the only extreme point of $\text{Ray}(\bar x,\text{d})$ is $\bar x$. where  $$\text{Ray}(\bar x,\text{d}):=\{\bar x+t\text{d}:t \ge 0\}$$

---

First of all for any $\bar x \ne z \in \text{Ray}(\bar x,\text{d})$, let $\lambda=1/2$ and $A=\bar x+t'/2\text{d},B=\bar x+3t'/2\text{d}$, where $z=\bar x+t'\text{d}$, so $$z=\frac{A+B}{2}$$ and $A\ne B$,
this shows that every point in $\text{Ray}(\bar x,\text{d})$ distinct from $\bar x$ is not an extreme point of $\text{Ray}(\bar x,\text{d})$.

Moreover let for some $x,y \in \text{Ray}(\bar x,\text{d})$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$:$\bar x=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$

Then this shows that for some $t_x,t_y \ge 0$:
$$\bar x=\lambda (\bar x+t_x\text{d})+(1-\lambda)(\bar x+t_y\text{d})$$

Which implies that $$\lambda t_x+(1-\lambda)t_y=0$$

But this does not show that $t_x=t_y$ and hence we cannot conclude that $x=y$ and then conclude that$\bar x$ is the only extreme point, so what should I do?

Comment: What is your definition of an "extreme point" of a ray? Or do you have a definition of "extreme point" in general [if so what definition] and are applying it to the ray you define?

Comment: @ coffeemath,
I have a definition of extreme point, for a non-empty set $S \subset \mathbb R^n$,a point $x$ in $S$ is called extreme point (of $S$), if it cannot be written as a strict convex combination of two distinct points in $S$, in other word if for some $y_1,y_2 \in S$ and some $\lambda \in (0,1)$ $$x=\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda) y_2$$ we conclude that $y_1=y_2$

Comment: Thanks for the definition. I'll try to look at it later, but likely someone here will annswer it before long. Good luck, and good question (+1)

Comment: To me it looks like theree are two things to check. 1) that $\bar x$ is an extreme point, and 2) that if $u$ is an element of the ray other than $\bar x$ then $u$ is not an extreme point. [You seem to be focused on (2), but to me your proof set-up is a bit more complicated than necessary.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at $\lambda t_x + (1 - \lambda) t_y = 0$, notice that the four terms $\lambda$, $t_x$, $(1 - \lambda)$, and $t_y$ are all nonnegative. In other words, $\lambda t_x + (1 - \lambda) t_y = 0$ can only be achieved if $\lambda t_x = 0$ and $(1 - \lambda)t_y = 0$. But neither $\lambda$ nor $1-\lambda$ can be $0$, since $\lambda \in (0, 1)$. It follows that $t_x = t_y = 0$.